# Referencing subfigures with subfigure package

Tags: captions, subfloats, article

I'm kinda new on LaTeX and I have a little problem. I'm using the `subfigure` package and trying to reference my subfigures with `\label{key}`, but appears "(??)" when I do that.

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx, multicol, latexsym, amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{booktabs}% for better rules in the table
\usepackage{anysize} % Soporte para el comando \marginsize
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\spanishdecimal{.}


%===================================================  


\begin{document}


\begingroup
\centering
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\subfigure[first caption.]{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{fig1a}}\label{fig:1a}
\subfigure[second caption.] {\includegraphics[width=0.185\textwidth]{fig1b}}\label{fig:1b}
\subfigure[third caption.]{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{fig1c}}\label{fig:1c}
\caption{General caption.} \label{fig:1}
\end{figure}

\endgroup

Using \ref{fig:1a} appears ``(??)'', but using \ref{fig1}, appears ``(1)''.

\end{document}
```

If someone could help me, I will appreciate it.

Greetings from South America.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `subfigure` is outdated/deprecated. Use `subfig` for or `subcaption` example instead

Comment: @Christian Hupfer: Or `floatrow`. Btw what is a subcaption example?

Comment: And remember that you have to run latex twice for it to produce all the cross references, if you don't you might be getting that ?? instead of the actual reference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is `subcaption` solution, which has to been used in its own box or environment (that's a little bit tedious) Otherwise, everything works like normal.

The optional argument to `\subcaption` , i.e. the one enclosed with `[...]` will appear in the List of Figures (Lof). If no such option is given, then the value of the mandatory argument `{...}` will go to the LoF.

If removed the `\begingroup...\endgroup` pair, since `\begin{figure}...\end{figure}` establishs grouping already.

```
\documentclass[11pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol, latexsym, amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tabu}
   \usepackage{booktabs}% for better rules in the table
\usepackage{anysize} % Soporte para el comando \marginsize
\usepackage{hyperref}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\spanishdecimal{.}


%===================================================  


\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
  \centering
\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{fig1a}
\subcaption[first caption.]{First}\label{fig:1a}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
  \centering
\includegraphics[width=0.185\textwidth]{fig1b}
\subcaption[second caption.]{Second}\label{fig:1b}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
  \centering
\includegraphics[width=0.185\textwidth]{fig1c}
\subcaption[third caption.]{Third}\label{fig:1c}
\end{minipage}

\caption{General caption.} \label{fig:1}
\end{figure}

Using \verb|\ref{fig:1a}| now appears as ``\ref{fig:1a}'' and using \verb|\ref{fig:1}|, appears ``\ref{fig:1}''.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome, it worked perfectly! 

Thank u very much.

Comment: Another question emerged: What can I do if a subcaption is too wide and overcomes the other image?

How can I separate both images? I read about commands \hfill, \quad and \qquad, but they didn't fixed it

Comment: The `\centering` before the `figure` doesn't really do anything I suppose. `subcaption`  loads `caption`, so loading the latter in addition is unnecessary. (I know all of that comes from the OPs code.)  And it might be useful to note that the optional argument to `subcaption` is what will be printed in the list of figures.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. You are right: I've used most of the code to get a working, but not elegant solution, I must admit

Comment: @KristiansenLLaraD: You can use other layouts, but this is another question indeed

Comment: Why using `minipages` (that you hate) and `subcaptions`? You can use `subfigure` and `subtable` (with a similar syntax to minipage) and use standard `caption`. More intuitive syntax.

Comment: @Johannes_B: You can readily provide another solution. I've never used `subcaption` so far -- the manual example used a minipage

Comment: The solution is similar. The part you are referring to is the basic setup, later the more comfortable stuff is introduced.

Answer (score 16):

Don't use `subfigure`, that has been obsolete for 15 years or so.

With `subfig` and its `\subfloat` command that substitute the obsolete package, the label should go in the optional argument (the one for the subcaption).

```
\documentclass[11pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % ensure your document is UTF-8
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % demo option just for testing
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\subfloat[first caption.\label{fig:1a}]{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{fig1a}}\hfill
\subfloat[second caption.\label{fig:1b}] {\includegraphics[width=0.185\textwidth]{fig1b}}\hfill
\subfloat[third caption.\label{fig:1c}]{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{fig1c}}
\caption{General caption.} \label{fig:1}
\end{figure}

Subfloat reference: \ref{fig:1a}

Figure reference: \ref{fig:1}

\end{document}
```

Note that `\begingroup\centering...\endgroup` around the figure is an error.

[image]

However, you may be wanting to use `subcaption`, that also behaves much better with `hyperref`.

```
\documentclass[11pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % ensure your document is UTF-8
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % demo option just for testing
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\setlength{\lineskip}{\medskipamount}
\subcaptionbox{first caption.\label{fig:1a}}{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{fig1a}}\hfill
\subcaptionbox{second caption.\label{fig:1b}}{\includegraphics[width=0.185\textwidth]{fig1b}}\hfill
\subcaptionbox{third caption.\label{fig:1c}}{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{fig1c}}
\caption{General caption.} \label{fig:1}
\end{figure}

Subfloat reference: \ref{fig:1a} 

Figure reference: \ref{fig:1}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is `subcaption` not compatible `center` environment?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who has to use the package subfigure, the issue can be resolved by shifting the label into the bracket like so:

```
\subfigure[first caption.]{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{fig1a}\label{fig:1a}}
```